# Android Webview content should not be lost on orientation change, but GUI should be updated properly

Tags: android, webview, orientation

I have been trying to keep the loaded page and javascript values of a WebView on orientation change and pausing the activity.
First I tried overriding configChanges, but that resulted in my GUI not being updated properly (i have a slidingdrawer that changes position on orientation change). After that i tried to put the WebView in a fragment and calling setRetainInstance(true); But this does not keep the content of the WebView intact. I tried keeping the same object alive by not recreating it, but android does not allow views to be re-used in that fashion.

my question is: is there any way to keep the contents of the webview without having to reload it on every orientation change, whilst having the other GUI components update properly.

I hope my question is clear enough, but i'd be happy to elaborate if there are any unclearities.

EDIT: i already tried adding android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in my manifest, that is what i meant by "overriding configchanges"

It seems like the only solution is to update all javascript variables again on orientation change. As I have not yet ran huge chunks of updates through javascript, I cannot provide much insight regarding the speed and resources of this operation.

Answer (score 4):

I know you already tried

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

but try this instead

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

In Android 3.2 and up "screen size" changes when you rotate which causes the webview to recreate itself.  see the linked answer below for more info.

I found this answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11903546/655822

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your androidmanifest file..... activity

```
android:name=".YourActivityHere" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: I already tried that, that is what i meant by overriding configChanges. When i implement this my GUI will not be recreated, and my slidindrawer for instance will not update properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this put this in manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

this in your class

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, that is what i meant by overriding configChanges. When i implement this my GUI will not be recreated, and my slidindrawer for instance will not update properly

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in android Manifest file.

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

Comment: I already tried that, that is what i meant by overriding configChanges. When i implement this my GUI will not be recreated, and my slidindrawer for instance will not update properly.