# Webview load to original stage when screen orientiation change in Android

Tags: php, android, webview, screen-orientation

Here my Activity class

```
 public class VisitmmActivity extends Activity{
 private WebView visitmmWebView;
 private static final String VISITMM_URL = "http://mobile.dev.fio/";

/**
 * called when activity is created
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntializeWebView();
}

public void IntializeWebView(){
    setContentView(R.layout.visitmm_main);
    visitmmWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_visitmm);

    visitmmWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    visitmmWebView.loadUrl(VISITMM_URL);

    WebSettings webSettings = visitmmWebView.getSettings();
    visitmmWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    visitmmWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    IntializeWebView();
}

/**
 * Make back works for browser history
 */
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && visitmmWebView.canGoBack()) {
        visitmmWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` is here

```
  <activity
        android:name=".seagames.visitmm.VisitmmActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
  </activity>
```

The problem is when I rotate screen on phone, application will load original stage (index.php). How can I fix it? I try to find out other solution. But, didn't work. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to find out **[this](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/)**! That's can solve this problem. But, I don't know what can cause other disadvantages. Because, some resource say "it's deprecated", "it's memory leak". Anyway, that's can solve. But, performance is a little slow when screen rotation.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.visitmm_main);
    visitmmWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_visitmm);
    visitmmWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = visitmmWebView.getSettings();
    visitmmWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    visitmmWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if(savedInstanceState ==null){
        visitmmWebView.loadUrl(VISITMM_URL);
    }
 }

 /**
 *  Save current activity or stage
 */

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    visitmmWebView.saveState(outState);
}

/**
 * Restore current activity on screen orientation
 */
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    visitmmWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't call InitialiseWebView() in onCongiurationChange() method.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12676439/254567) your answer for similar SO question

Comment: Okie, please let me check it. Thank @Pushkar Pendey

Comment: Yes, your right! So, I already update code in my own answer. Thank buddy!